# Losing data with the goroutines

Tags: sql-server, go, aws-lambda, goroutine

I am writing an AWS lambda code to query an RDS table, Convert it to JSON, and return it. But I don't see all the records in the JSON than what SQL query has returned. Say I am querying 1500 records from the table but there are only 1496 to 1500 records in the JSON (0-5 records less) every time. I doubt I have messed up something with the `sync.WaitGroup`.

**Below is the SQL Server Query**

```
SELECT TOP 1500 * FROM IMBookingApp.dbo.BA_Contact__c
WHERE ContactId > 0
```

**Below is my code**

```
// Convert the rows object to slice of objects for every row
func parseRow(rows *sql.Rows, totalColumns int) []string {

    receiver := make([]string, totalColumns)

    is := make([]interface{}, len(receiver))
    for i := range is {
        is[i] = &receiver[i]
    }

    err := rows.Scan(is...)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error reading rows: " + err.Error())
    }

    TotalRecordsInParseRowfunction++
    return receiver
}

// Query the given table and return JSON response
func queryTable(conn *sql.DB, query string) (string, error) {

    // Query Table
    rows, err := conn.Query(query)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("DATABASE ERROR:", err)
        return "", errors.New("DATABASE ERROR:" + err.Error())
    }

    println("Rows:", rows)
    defer rows.Close()

    // Get the column names
    columns, err := rows.Columns()
    // fmt.Println("columns", columns)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("DATABASE ERROR:", err)
        return "", errors.New("DATABASE ERROR:" + err.Error())
    }

    totalColumns := len(columns)
    var resp []map[string]string // Declare the type of final response which will be used to create JSON
    var waitgroup sync.WaitGroup

    // Iterate over all the rows returned
    for rows.Next() {

        waitgroup.Add(1)
        TotalRecordsCount++
        row := parseRow(rows, totalColumns)

        go func() {
            // Create a map of the row
            respRow := map[string]string{} // Declare the type of each row of response
            for count := range row {
                respRow[columns[count]] = row[count]
            }
            // fmt.Println("\n\nrespRow", respRow)

            resp = append(resp, respRow)
            TotalRecordsAppendedCount++
            waitgroup.Done()
        }()
    }
    waitgroup.Wait()

    // If no rows are returned
    if len(resp) == 0 {
        fmt.Println("MESSAGE: No records are available")
        return "", errors.New("MESSAGE: No records are available")
    }

    // Create JSON
    respJSON, _ := json.Marshal(resp)
    fmt.Println("Response", string(respJSON))

    fmt.Println("\n--------------Summary---------------")
    fmt.Println("TotalRecordsInParseRowfunction", TotalRecordsInParseRowfunction)
    fmt.Println("TotalRecordsCount", TotalRecordsCount)
    fmt.Println("TotalRecordsAppendedCount", TotalRecordsAppendedCount)
    fmt.Println("Object Length", len(resp))

    return string(respJSON), nil // Return JSON

}
```

**Below is the output summary I am getting**

```
--------------Summary---------------
TotalRecordsInParseRowfunction 1500
TotalRecordsCount 1500
TotalRecordsAppendedCount 1500
Object Length 1496
```

Comment: What happens when you add a mutex (declared before your `for` loop in `queryTable`) that is locked before `resp = append(resp, respRow)` and then unlocked after it? Maybe some items get lost there

Comment: I haven't used `mutex` before. Let me try it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is racy. Multiple goroutines are writing to `resp` without any mutual exclusion, so you lose data.

You may add a mutex lock-unlock around that. However, the code you have in the goroutine does not warrant its own goroutine because it is a simple map addition. Dealing with that code in the goroutine will be a lot easier and probably it'll run much faster without the goroutine scheduling overhead. Unless you are planning to have more logic in that goroutine, I suggest you remove it.

Here's some more information about what's probably going on: first of all, in the current version of go, a goroutine will only yield to others when that goroutine calls some of the library functions. Looking at the code, it is unlikely that your goroutines will ever yield. Since you already observed data loss (which means there is a race condition), you probably have more than one cores.

The race is here:

```
resp = append(resp, respRow)
```

Without mutual exclusion, one goroutine may look at `resp`, sees that it can write to its `n`th element. Another goroutine (running on a separate core) can do the same, and writes there successfully. But the first goroutine still thinks that element is empty, so overwrites it, and updates `resp`. When this happens, you lose one element.

If you add mutual exclusion to this code, you'll essentially force all goroutines to run sequentially because they are not really doing anything else. Also, since goroutine execution ordering is random, you'll end up with a randomly ordered `resp`. In short, this is one of those instances where you should execute the code sequentially.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have added mutex in the code still some rows are getting missed. You can see my changes here - https://play.golang.org/p/_IyB6XdfInv

Comment: You are creating a separate mutex for each row, so you're not really preventing a race. Move mutex declaration outside the for loop.

Comment: Correct. It worked now. Still, I would like to optimize my code. I am not sure I completely understood what you are saying here - `Dealing with that code in the goroutine will be a lot easier and probably it'll run much faster without the goroutine scheduling overhead. Unless you are planning to have more logic in that goroutine` As I am new to Golang, frankly I don't understand goroutines much. But I think my code will be processing around 3K rows at a time, that's why I have used goroutines here. Do you think we should avoid it here?

Comment: Yes. The amount of work you're doing in that goroutine is very small, and you have a shared resource. If you create 3k goroutines, you're creating 3k*2k stack space, and all goroutines are waiting on a lock. You can use channels, but still, the amount of work you're doing is really small. Measure and see.

Comment: "3K rows" is not an estimation of the resources _per se._ In order for concurrent processing of multiple packs each of 3K rows to have sense, the amount of CPU cycles spent to process such a pack _independently_ from all the other packs must be considerable; otherwise there will be no performance gain, and may be a net performance loss.

Comment: It may not be directly spent CPU time (like crunching some math on the data from those rows) but rather things like peforming queries to external data sources etc. The key point is that such activities must be themselves parallelizable.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have calculated the total execution time of the script with and without the goroutine. And It is almost the same for my code. Definitely, I should think of removing it. Thanks for your suggestions.